# How to read two IR File within one LLVMContext?

Tags: c++, c, function, llvm, llvm-ir

For example, I have two IR files named `a.ll` and `b.ll`.
Both IR file contain the same struct type named `Foo`. `b.ll` contains a function named `hello`.
I want to add the declaration of function `hello` into `a.ll`.

When I call `parseIRFile()` with the same `LLVMContext`, the same struct type `Foo` in `a.ll` and `b.ll` are renamed to something like `%struct.Foo.1` and `%struct.Foo.2`. Thus the function declaration is incompatible with the function in `b.ll`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: That wasn't possible when I needed it, and I wrote [a patch to solve it](https://reviews.llvm.org/D60616), which I couldn't get merged. I think the patch is fine and I expect I could get it merged if I asked a few more times, but it's difficult to know when one starts being annoying, and it wasn't important to me. So use at your own risk. It'll need a few changes for the most modern LLVM, nothing significant.

Comment: Do you need them to be two modules or can you use the module linker? The module linker will detect same-named (or with .number suffix) identical structs and merge them.